# jQuery Multiple $(this) not working

Tags: jquery

I use two $(this) in a function but the second $(this) is not working

```
$('.port-cat li').on( 'click', function() {
$(this).addClass('current-cat').siblings().removeClass('current-cat');
$(this).parents('.portfolio_cat').removeClass('current-cat'); // this code not working });
```

But If I remove the first $(this) then the code will start working

```
$('.port-cat li').on( 'click', function() {
$(this).parents('.portfolio_cat').removeClass('current-cat'); // it's working now });
```

How to make the both $(this) code working without removing one?

Comment: $(this).parents('.portfolio_cat').removeClass('current-cat'); does the parent  has 'current-cat' class as well?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have add an other class by use

```
$(this).addClass('current-cat').siblings().removeClass('current-cat');
```

so the li element now has two class. You can't use $(this) any more, but you could use $("classname") to replace $(this).

Comment: Neither `$(this)` or `this` change in this function so I have no idea why you say you can't use `$(this)` any more if you want to operate on the same elements in the second line of code as in the first line of code.

Comment: I think you can use the developers tools in Google Chrome to create a  breakpoint and see what is the second $(this) refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
  var selectedElement=$(this);
      selectedElement.addClass('current-cat').siblings().removeClass('current-cat');
    selectedElement.parents('.portfolio_cat').removeClass('current-cat');
```

Comment: this is the way to go!

Comment: why not ? instead of defining $(this), i created a selector var & assigned :)

Comment: exactly! I was agreeing with your answer!

Answer (score 0):

1. in your JavaScript write `console.log("1st this: ", $(this));` and `console.log("2nd this: ", $(this));` right by both `$(this)` instances.
2. Open **Chrome Dev Tools** (or Firefox Dev Tools) with `F12`, or `right-click + inspect element`.
3. Go to the **Console** tab.
4. run your code.
5. are both **this**es the same object as you presumed? If so, I'll keep looking for the answer.

meanwhile: storing `$(this);` in a variable beforehand. Is a legitimate simple answer.